# how to set properties for label and point correctly?

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I am trying to add points to a map.

```
point : {
                    pixelSize : 8,
                    color : Cesium.Color.BLACK,
                    outlineColor : Cesium.Color.WHITE,
                    outlineWidth : 1
                },
                label : {
                    text : data[1][i]['name'],
                    font : '20pt Lucida Console',
                    horizontalOrigin:Cesium.HorizontalOrigin.LEFT,
                    verticalOrigin:Cesium.VerticalOrigin.CENTER,
                    outlineWidth:3,
                    pixelOffset: new Cesium.Cartesian2(20,0),
                    fillColor:Cesium.Color.BLACK,
                    outlineColor:Cesium.Color.WHITE,
                    style: Cesium.LabelStyle.FILL_AND_OUTLINE
                }
```

some properties don't work and are equal to undefined. I think I made a syntax error. What can be wrong?

Comment: Please elaborate on what properties are not working, and how they are not working (such as an error log). Also it would help to include what 'data' and 'Cesium' is.

Comment: @zemaj cesium is the tagged library being used

Comment: @zemaj, properties color, outlineColor, pixelOffset do not work. this is basic. there is no error log, as you can see these properties are set but equal to undefined

Answer (score 0):

solution

```
color: {
    rgba: [255, 0, 0, 255],
},
outlineColor: {
    rgba: [255, 255, 255, 255],
},
```